# Procedure to fetch facebook data in to hadoop using NiFi processors

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-nifi

Is there is any possible way to fetch facebook data to hdfs using NiFi processors? I did not find even a single source or sample so far regarding this case ...If it possible? What will be the procedure?

Comment: I donot have idea about Nifi but you can use Flume to fetch facebok data and store in HDFS.

Comment: Since i working on Nifi ,i need to process the facebook data in Nifi only

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the HTTP processors (GetHttp, PostHttp, InvokeHttp) to interact with Facebook APIs. In the case of the OpenGraph API (and probably others), you need HTTPS so you'll have to set up an SSL Context and such. There is a good exchange at https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/20424/add-certificates-facebook-to-apache-nifi.html explaining how to do this.

Once the data is out of Facebook and in your flow, you can use PutHDFS to write the files into Hadoop.